# Copy paste is not working in command prompt neither right click or keyboard shortcuts

Tags: console, digital-ocean, magento2, cloud-hosting

When I'm using console of digital-ocean then some operations are not working like paste through keyboard, right click of mouse and scrolling of console.

Comment: DigitalOcean’s Droplet console allows you to paste content since August 14, 2018, as per their official [release notes](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/release-notes/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following script (Found it [here](https://www.gregoryvarghese.com/how-to-copy-and-paste-into-the-digital-ocean-vnc-console/), Originally posted by @Dave Butler as commented below):

```
!function(){function t(){function n(t,e){s=s.concat(RFB.messages.keyEvent(t,e))}var o=e.shift(),s=[],i=o.charCodeAt(),c=-1!=='!@#$%^&*()_+{}:"<>?~|'.indexOf(o),r=XK_Shift_L;c&&n(r,1),n(i,1),n(i,0),c&&n(r,0),rfb._sock.send(s),e.length>0&&setTimeout(t,10)}var e=prompt("Enter text to be sent to console").split("");t()}();
```

1. Open browser console (F12 / Ctrl+Shift+J on chrome).
2. Paste it in.
3. Replace "Enter text to be sent to console" with the desired command.
4. Press enter.

Comment: I believe the code on that blog was taken from my gist: https://gist.github.com/croepha/7b53f211ae4be3c526c3 first revision in 2015

Comment: Is my edit fair @Dave Butler? Feel free to answer yourself and i will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found their console to be pretty terrible. Have downloaded putty and now ssh into it from there - works a charm for speed & copy/pasting etc.